# Silverlight: how to uninstall out-of-browser application

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to uninstall out-of-browser app. I'd read a manual, and found the following command:

```
   1: "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" 

   2:     /uninstall 

   3:     /origin:http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/apps/facebookclient/ClientBin/Silverface.xap
```

what is /origin?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735621/uninstall-out-of-browser-silverlight-application-programmatically

Comment: well,.. I think that's about a bit different situation. Can someone write a command to uninstall an App

Answer (score 1):

Switch `/origin` is the original URL that you downloaded/installed/run that `Silverlight` xap file from.

In your given example it is:

> http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/apps/facebookclient/ClientBin/Silverface.xap

That is the place it will look for updates if available.

Comment: You can find the url in <user folder>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\<AppFolderName>\metadata file under FinalAppUri entry.